# Clarification about the terminology of Hypothesis testing

Tags: hypothesis-testing, terminology

I have a Hypothesis $H_0:$ A person has  Corona, $H_1$: The person does not have corona. I know that
\begin{aligned}
\alpha &= \mathbb{P}_{\theta_0}(X\in \text{Reject H}_0), \\ 
1-\beta &= \mathbb{P}_{\theta_1}(X\in \text{Reject H}_0).
\end{aligned}

My reasoning says that $1-\alpha$ should be the sensitivity of the test, and $1-\beta$ that is the Power of the test should be the specificity of the test.

I am getting confused because everywhere I read It says the opposite. Can somebody clarify this for me

Comment: You appear to have mixed up the null and alternative hypotheses.  That doesn't matter in this simple situation where each hypothesis is "simple" (specifying its parameters completely), so it can be confusing.  Consider studying some of the [classic textbook situations.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=null+hypothesis+alternat*+)

Comment: What if this situation is what I am testing, I framed the null in such a way that I do not want it to be true. Are the mathematical equations wrong?

Comment: Then you have to accept that your choice of framing the question changes the default meanings of sensitivity and specificity.

Comment: So in the default case it is assumed that $H_0$: Person does not have Corona.  is that the case according to which sensitivity and specificity have been defined in general

Comment: @Upstart if you are actually dealing with a diagnostic tool, there is no need to refer to hypothesis testing at all. We usually just refer to our test, and then we report its sensitivity and specificity. The lack of condition as a "negative" or a "null" value is perhaps a commonality, but building a well defined bridge between hypothesis testing and diagnostic evaluation doesn't seem to be the point of your question.

Comment: Diagnostic instruments have the additional benefit that we can report the positive or negative predictive value, and the overall accuracy as well. Unlike NHST, we observe patients with and without the condition and each has one or more test results usually. The same is not true in hypothesis testing - there is in fact only one truth. Making inference about a *single* person's disease status doesn't make sense from a frequentist point of view.